# How to add a newly created Li to Localstorage whtiout getting back the previously created Elemnts

Tags: javascript, html

I have a UL, that have a default Li's, also ability to create other Li's if needed problem is once I load the HTML from local storage it duplicate the default elements my point is I want to save only the newly created elements and load them later, not the new elements + the current, I tried to give the newly created elements a specific class and used get elements by classname also queryselector and both of those methods returned HTML collection or node-list which is undefined, any solution to this issue so I could isolated the newly created elements to the local storage. thanks for your effort and time in advance.

```js
const dayslist = document.getElementById('list');
function create() {

    const createLi = `<li>new</li><li>new</li><li>new</li><li>new</li>`;
    dayslist.innerHTML += createLi;
    let html = dayslist.innerHTML;
    localStorage.setItem('content', html);
}



function onLoad() {
    if (localStorage.getItem('content')) {
        dayslist.innerHTML += localStorage.getItem('content');
    }
}

onLoad();
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <h1>The ul element</h1>

    <ul id=list>
        <li>Coffee</li>
        <li>Tea</li>
        <li>Milk</li>
        <div onclick="create()">
            <span>create!!</span>
        </div>

    </ul>

</body>
<script src="/js.js"></script>

</html>
```

Comment: Just as a heads up you should not be setting innerHTML from local storage as this can be a security vulnerability. (Not sure if you are just using it as an example or if you intend on doing this in production, so thought I would just warn you)

Answer (score 0):

```
function create() {
    const dayslist = document.getElementById('list');

    const createLi = `<li>new</li>`;
    dayslist.innerHTML += createLi;

    // Appending the newly created LIs and storing into local storage
    const prevContent = localStorage.getItem('content');
    const newContent = prevContent ? prevContent + createLi : createLi;
    localStorage.setItem('content', newContent);
}
```